# Django social app integration, auth namespace is not recognised?

Tags: django, django-1.9

I am having problem with facebook login app integration the problem is

```
'auth' is not a registered namespace
```

the problematic part is the:

```
 <p>
            {% if user and not user.is_anonymous %}
                Hello {{ user.get_full_name|default:user.username }}!
            {% else %}
                I don't think we've met before
            {% endif %}
        </p>
        <a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'facebook' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login</a>
        <a href="{% url 'auth:logout' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Logout</a>
```

I got that auth is not recognized but in the tutorial there were no problem with that. I am using django versio 1.9.5.

Comment: Hi @KocielnyWizard - could you provide me with your `urls.py` file for your project.

Comment: Bloody Hell Bro I found the mistake myself. Namespace was something else then I changed it to 'auth'. Thanks bro for your help!

Comment: No worries. Always something frustratingly simple! :)